# How to make changing "screens" in c#

Tags: c#

I'm new in C#, and I wanted to know if there was any way to show a screen with certain elements, and then with the click of a button, switch to another screen, similar to an installer.

From my experience in Java, I would just use a few `JPanel`s and then hide only the one i want visible.

However, I'm new to C# forms and it's very different from Java swing. Anyone understand my problem and can tell me pretty much how this works? Thanks.

Comment: WinForms is actually pretty similar to Swing - and the exact same approach *would* work. However, there are a number of useful "Wizard" (hint: keyword) controls/tutorials available to make the task easier.

Comment: I see many different types of panels, but how do I show one of them and hide the others? I'm using Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: How would you do it in Swing? [Just translate the API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.visible(v=vs.110).aspx) (but do perform some basic research on "Wizards" first :)

Comment: Thanks, I'll experiment with this a little bit.

Comment: Wpf or windows forms?

Comment: I'm using Windows forms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Simple approach**

Just use a `Grid` with multiple `Grid`s inside of it.  Set the `Visibility` property of each internal `Grid` (except the first one you want to show) to `Hidden` or `Collapsed`, and then set them to `Visible` when you want to display them.

**Better approach**

Create a class for each section, each of which derives from the same parent class.  Create a `DataTemplate` for the parent class, then just have instances of the template load into the original `Grid` through a `ContentPresenter`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this creating new forms. From my experience I've tried this:

```
Form2 formTwo = new Form2(); // creates instance
formTwo.Show(); // displays the new form
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized; // minimizes previous form
this.ShowInTaskbar = false; // hides it from taskbar
```

Keep in mind that this does not close the previous form. I would recommend setting `ShowIntaskbar` as `True` if you don't mind the user seeing the form minimized.

EDIT: If you want to show new elements I suggest you can try adding a new `Form` class to the project then using the designer.